# Spacing between custom titleView and back button on navbar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, spacing

I have a problem of spacing in navbar between back button (without title) and custom titleView (Just 2 labels embed in vertical stackView). I try to explain that on sceens below (you can see what device is in title of screenshots [iPhone 5s & iPhone 6 Plus] and if it's debug mode).

[image: iPhone 5s]

[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

In advance thank you for your help.

Comment: in stack view have property distribution which set or not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is not the stackView because it is configured with distribution vertically and the width of titleView is sizeToFit

Comment: @O.Boujaouane did you ever fix this? I have the same problem!